# How to find all possible "continuous" paths of a matrix / network / graph in R

Tags: r, matrix, igraph, graph-theory

I am interested in determining all of the possible "continuous" paths of an NxN matrix in R and returning their result. By "continuous" I mean that we can travel without lifting up your pencil/digit. That is, we can move up, down, left, right, or diagonally.

To make this concrete, let's use a 3x3 matrix example:

```
mat_3x3 <- matrix(LETTERS[1:9], ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)
mat_3x3
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,] "A"  "B"  "C" 
# [2,] "D"  "E"  "F" 
# [3,] "G"  "H"  "I"
```

This means we have the following valid and invalid paths:

[image: valid and invalid paths]

Some considerations:

- The start position does not need to be position `A` (1, 1).
- We cannot "double-back" or touch the same cell multiple times.
- Short paths are possible (e.g. `A -> B -> C` is a valid path; likewise, `A -> E -> I`) -- that is, we **do not** need to pass through all the nodes.

If there is a package or concept that facilitates, please advise (most of the graph traversal packages I have seen are more "graph" than "matrix"). I'd imagine dynamic programming or recursion is probably of use here, but I am not sure how to start.

---

I believe the answer to the 2X2 case could be 60 per the following solution for one cell with paths = 15; 15 * 4 = 60:

[image: 2x2 case for one cell]

However, things escalate quickly for a 3x3, 4x4, case...no longer just corners, the addition of "center" squares, etc...

---

If we think about this problem as more of a graph or network, we have the following for the 3X3 case:

[image: network or graph visualization]

**Why though?**
I am just genuinely interested in this problem and find it fascinating. I'd like to understand how to program it in `R`, but I'd consider other answers if they exist (then perhaps translate them to `R`). It started as a thought experiment thinking about a "game" where you you slide your finger on a touch screen to create words from the string of characters. Rather than minimum cost, we'd like to maximize score -- using a `Z` scores more points than an `E` like in [Scrabble](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrabble_letter_distributions), etc. But I suppose this has interesting applications in social networks, graph theory, transportation optimization, and other domains.

Comment: You can build a graph that looks like a matrix. Here is one [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59524874/python-iterate-through-connected-components-in-grayscale-image/59561214#59561214) in Python.

Comment: I would start by trying to figure out an appropriate algorithm, *then* worrying about how to implement it in R.  Googling "find all paths grid" seems like a reasonable start, although most of them are designed for finding paths between two particular nodes, rather than finding all paths that cover every node in the grid ...

Comment: I agree with Ben, find the proper methodology first is important. Given the assumption that each node is a unique id, though, leads me to think that `combinat::permn(m)` will give you the order of nodes for each possible traversal of nodes. 9 nodes produces 362,880 (`factorial(9)`) permutations, though, so now you have the problem of what to do with those.

Comment: there is a solution here although it is not in R https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13410168/how-many-ways-to-visit-all-the-points-of-a-given-matrix

Comment: You could make a list of all illegal moves (e.g., the path can't move from A to C, F, G, H, or I) and search the list of permutations for these illegal moves. Any paths that remain satisfy your requirements. This is a slow method but would work.

Comment: Oh, I thought the path had to pass through all of the nodes ... What's your use case? How big a grid are you actually going to try this with ... ?

Comment: @BenBolker, so did I, that puts it well over 600,000. \*shrug\*

Comment: @BenBolker, 5x5 is probably a safe stop. I just find this problem fascinating. Stems from thinking about a "game" where you slide your finger on a touch screen to create words from the string of characters. Rather than minimum cost, we'd like to maximize score -- using a `Z` scores more than an `E`, etc.

Comment: Is it not like finding all the path without cycle between all the possible pairs of nodes in the graph you defined?

Comment: @glagla Almost. Not just pairs. But without cycles is correct. I feel like it can be phrased as an undirected graph problem or find all subgraphs, etc. just not up to date on my verbiage. `A-B-D` is legit, `E-H-I-F` is legit, ...

Comment: by pairs I meant all possible combinations of two nodes (I want to know all path between A and D, between E and F, etc)

Answer (score 1):

This will work any size matrix (limited by hardware) and does not require the matrix to be rectangular e.g. 3 x 4.  It builds a validity matrix that has all of the original matrix positions as columns and the row will return `TRUE` if it's a valid move and `FALSE` if not.  I didn't validate all results, but the spot checks I did worked.

```
library(gtools)

# convert matrix to numbers to reference by position
m <- matrix(seq_along(mat_3x3), ncol = ncol(mat_3x3))

# create blank matrix that is used to see if it is a valid move
mLength <- length(m)
mValid <- matrix(rep(FALSE, mLength ^ 2), ncol = mLength)

# create index to generate validity matrix
xIndex <- seq_len(ncol(m))
yIndex <- seq_len(nrow(m))

# wrap with NA to prevent out of bounds
mBounds <- rbind(NA, cbind(NA, m, NA), NA)

# set validity matrix TRUE if returns a value that is not NA
mValid[cbind(as.vector(mBounds[yIndex + 1, xIndex + 2]), seq_len(mLength))] <- TRUE
mValid[cbind(as.vector(mBounds[yIndex + 2, xIndex + 2]), seq_len(mLength))] <- TRUE
mValid[cbind(as.vector(mBounds[yIndex + 2, xIndex + 1]), seq_len(mLength))] <- TRUE
mValid[cbind(as.vector(mBounds[yIndex + 2, xIndex    ]), seq_len(mLength))] <- TRUE
mValid[cbind(as.vector(mBounds[yIndex + 1, xIndex    ]), seq_len(mLength))] <- TRUE
mValid[cbind(as.vector(mBounds[yIndex    , xIndex    ]), seq_len(mLength))] <- TRUE
mValid[cbind(as.vector(mBounds[yIndex    , xIndex + 1]), seq_len(mLength))] <- TRUE
mValid[cbind(as.vector(mBounds[yIndex    , xIndex + 2]), seq_len(mLength))] <- TRUE

# define function to check if provided sequence is valid
validate <- function(x) {
  all(mValid[cbind(x[-1], x[-length(x)])])
}

# generate all permutations
p1 <- permutations(mLength, mLength)
p2 <- apply(p1, 1, validate)
p2 <- p1[p2, ]

# some results
> mat_3x3[p2[1, ]]
[1] "A" "D" "G" "E" "B" "C" "F" "H" "I"

> mat_3x3[p2[531, ]]
[1] "C" "E" "H" "G" "D" "A" "B" "F" "I"
```

To generate other sequences that do not use all letters would require changing the `permutations` function above to limit the target vector length:

```
p1 <- permutations(mLength, mLength - 1)
p2 <- apply(p1, 1, validate)
p2 <- p1[p2, ]

> mat_3x3[p2[1701, ]]
[1] "C" "F" "B" "D" "G" "E" "I" "H"
```

Using `combinat::permn` to use the `validate` function while building the permutations.

```
library(combinat)
p <- list()
pTemp <- permn(mLength, function(x) x[validate(x)])
p[[mLength]] <- pTemp[lengths(pTemp) > 0]

# breaking all paths that use every option into smaller pieces to find shorter paths
for (i in seq_len(mLength)[-mLength]) {
  pTemp <- lapply(p[[mLength]], function(x, y) embed(rev(x), length(x) - y), y = i)
  p[[mLength - i]] <- unique(do.call(rbind, pTemp))
}

# total number of paths
sum(unlist(lapply(p, nrow)), length(p[[mLength]]))
```

Comment: I like this. I wonder if it'd be possible to leverage `combinat::permn` instead of `gtools::permutations` to do the `validate` function "on-the-fly"

Comment: @JasonAizkalns updated to use `combinat::permn` and all shorter paths.  However, a better method of building the permutations might be required as increasing the matrix size quickly hits memory limits.

Comment: Thank you. I posted [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59762657/2572423) which may give some clues/ideas. I haven't had time to dig too deeply yet.