# How to perform a check on a permutation "on-the-fly" without storing the result in R

Tags: r, permutation

Assume we have the following permutations of the letters, "a", "b", and "c":

```
library(combinat)
do.call(rbind, permn(letters[1:3]))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,] "a"  "b"  "c" 
# [2,] "a"  "c"  "b" 
# [3,] "c"  "a"  "b" 
# [4,] "c"  "b"  "a" 
# [5,] "b"  "c"  "a" 
# [6,] "b"  "a"  "c"
```

Is it possible to perform some function on a given permutation "on-the-fly" (i.e., a particular row) without storing the result?

That is, if the `row == "a" "c" "b"` or `row == "b" "c" "a"`, do not store the result. The desired result in this case would be:

```
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,] "a"  "b"  "c" 
# [2,] "c"  "a"  "b" 
# [3,] "c"  "b"  "a" 
# [4,] "b"  "a"  "c"
```

I know I can apply a function to all the permutations on the fly within `combinat::permn` with the `fun` argument such as:

```
permn(letters[1:3], fun = function(x) {
  res <- paste0(x, collapse = "")
  if (res == "acb" | res == "bca") {
    return(NA)
  } else {
    return(res)
  }
})
```

But this stills stores an `NA` and the returned list has 6 elements instead of the desired 4 elements:

```
# [[1]]
# [1] "abc"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] NA
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] "cab"
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] "cba"
# 
# [[5]]
# [1] NA
# 
# [[6]]
# [1] "bac"
```

Note, I am not interested in subsequently removing the `NA` values; I am specifically interested in not appending to the result list "on-the-fly" for a given permutation.

Comment: Will this work ? `do.call(rbind, permn(letters[1:3], fun = function(x) {
  res <- paste0(x, collapse = "");
  if (!res %in% c("acb","bca"))
    return(res)
}))`

Comment: If you return `NULL` instead of `NA`, then the subsequent `rbind` will not show anything. Since `rbind(1,NULL)` gives just `1`. Which is pretty much what Ronak is suggesting too. But I think there will always be at least an empty list object.

Answer (score 2):

We could use a magrittr pipeline where we rbind the input matrix to the Rows to be checked and omit the duplicate rows.

```
library(combinat)
library(magrittr)

Rows <- rbind(c("a", "c", "b"), c("b", "c", "a"))

do.call(rbind, permn(letters[1:3])) %>% 
  subset(tail(!duplicated(rbind(Rows, .)), -nrow(Rows)))
```

giving:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] "a"  "b"  "c" 
[2,] "c"  "a"  "b" 
[3,] "c"  "b"  "a" 
[4,] "b"  "a"  "c"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `return` `NULL` for the particular condition that you want to ignore and `rbind` the result which will ignore the NULL elements and bind only the combinations that you need.

```
do.call(rbind, combinat::permn(letters[1:3], function(x) 
   if(!all(x == c("a", "c", "b") | x == c("b", "c", "a")))
   return(x)
))

#    [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,] "a"  "b"  "c" 
#[2,] "c"  "a"  "b" 
#[3,] "c"  "b"  "a" 
#[4,] "b"  "a"  "c"
```

Similarly,

```
do.call(rbind, permn(letters[1:3],function(x) { 
   res <- paste0(x, collapse = "")
  if (!res %in% c("acb","bca")) 
    return(res) 
}))

#      [,1] 
#[1,] "abc"
#[2,] "cab"
#[3,] "cba"
#[4,] "bac"
```